# How do I find the closest match to a string key within a C++ map?

Tags: c++

I am making a program, and one feature I would like to implement is a error-checking type of thing, where if the C++ program searches through the program and *doesn't* find a match, it will return the closest matching string.

I currently have a setup like so:

```
help_data["invite"] = "**How to use?**\n `/invite` - *No other parameters* \n **Purpose** \n To generate an invite for Beyond!";
help_data["help"] = "**How to use?** \n `/help [command]` \n **Purpose** \n To generate an embed on how a specific command works, and its' syntax.";
```

```
std::string command = std::get<std::string>(event.get_parameter("command"));
    std::transform(command.begin(), command.end(), command.begin(), ::tolower); //lowercase
    if (help_data.find(command) == help_data.end()) {
        // Not Found
        event.reply(dpp::ir_channel_message_with_source, dpp::message().set_content("Unable to find help data for command `" + command + "`"));
    }
    else {
        // Found
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't.  `map` is optimized for exact matches and doesn't have any facilities for close matches.

Comment: Alright, thank you for letting me know, I'm still pretty much a beginner lol.

Comment: Note that if you want the closest match in terms of *sorting*, you can use `equal_range` (or its two halves, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` - they will be equal, thus form an empty range, if the match is not exact). This can be used if you want to check prefixes (but isn't limited to them).

Comment: @MarkRansom: `map` is indeed optimized, but not for exact matches, that's the job of `unordered_map`. With `map`, you gain `equal_range` for lexiographical closest matches. That's one form of "closest match", but not a closest match for typical UX scenario's. Still, optimizing error scenario's for speed is rarely useful. You can still traverse all keys of a `map` and do manual matches.

Comment: @MSalters OK I give you that one - `equal_range` can be useful if you're looking for close matches that differ only at the end of the string.  But it's useless for finding close matches at the beginning of the string; for that you need to iterate the whole container as you said.  And once you've decided to iterate the whole container the choice of container is almost irrelevant - a `vector` might be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part 1** (see Part 2 and 3 below)

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236962/how-do-i-find-the-closest-match-to-a-string-key-within-a-c-map#comment124159226_70236962) by @BasileStarynkevitch, you can implement [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which measures edit distance (number of insertions, deletions, substitutions) between two strings, or in other words how similar two strings are, the closer value of Levenstein distance to 0 the more strings are similar.

Just now I implemented from scratch this distance computation in C++. And showed an example of using this distance function to find closest string among given strings to the query string.

Function `Levenstein()` is implemented according to WikiPedia (link above), and is not optimized only to make it easy to read and understand, for educational purposes. In production code to make it much faster use [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique (cache results of same function calls), because as you can see my implementation will be quite slow for larger strings, for same two strings it will do a lot of redundant same function calls. Another way to speed up computation is to use [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach to cache and reuse previous results inside array.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/8r7hjar3q)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

size_t Levenstein(std::string_view const & a, std::string_view const & b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
    if (b.size() == 0)
        return a.size();
    if (a.size() == 0)
        return b.size();
    if (a[0] == b[0])
        return Levenstein(a.substr(1), b.substr(1));
    return 1 + std::min(
        std::min(
            Levenstein(a          , b.substr(1)),
            Levenstein(a.substr(1), b          )
        ),  Levenstein(a.substr(1), b.substr(1))
    );
}

std::tuple<size_t, size_t> FindClosest(
        std::vector<std::string> const & strs, std::string const & query) {
    size_t minv = size_t(-1), mini = size_t(-1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
        size_t const dist = Levenstein(strs[i], query);
        if (dist < minv) {
            minv = dist;
            mini = i;
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(mini, minv);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> const strs = {"world", "worm", "work"};
    std::string const query = "word";
    auto const [idx, dist] = FindClosest(strs, query);
    std::cout << "Closest to '" << query << "' is '"
        << strs[idx] << "', distance " << dist << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Closest to 'word' is 'world', distance 1
```

---

**Part 2**

As suggested in Part 1 of answer, I decided to implement optimized version of Levenstein distance using [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique to store and reuse same results in array.

This version is a bit harder to understand and longer to read, but is much faster to run.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/js3YGzfMn)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

size_t Levenstein(std::string_view const & a, std::string_view const & b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
    std::vector<size_t> d_((a.size() + 1) * (b.size() + 1), size_t(-1));
    auto d = [&](size_t ia, size_t ib) -> size_t & {
        return d_[ia * (b.size() + 1) + ib];
    };
    std::function<size_t(size_t, size_t)> LevensteinInt =
        [&](size_t ia, size_t ib) -> size_t {
            if (d(ia, ib) != size_t(-1))
                return d(ia, ib);
            size_t dist = 0;
            if (ib >= b.size())
                dist = a.size() - ia;
            else if (ia >= a.size())
                dist = b.size() - ib;
            else if (a[ia] == b[ib])
                dist = LevensteinInt(ia + 1, ib + 1);
            else
                dist = 1 + std::min(
                    std::min(
                        LevensteinInt(ia,     ib + 1),
                        LevensteinInt(ia + 1, ib    )
                    ),  LevensteinInt(ia + 1, ib + 1)
                );
            d(ia, ib) = dist;
            return dist;
        };
    return LevensteinInt(0, 0);
}

std::tuple<size_t, size_t> FindClosest(
        std::vector<std::string> const & strs, std::string const & query) {
    size_t minv = size_t(-1), mini = size_t(-1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
        size_t const dist = Levenstein(strs[i], query);
        if (dist < minv) {
            minv = dist;
            mini = i;
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(mini, minv);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> const strs = {"world", "worm", "work"};
    std::string const query = "word";
    auto const [idx, dist] = FindClosest(strs, query);
    std::cout << "Closest to '" << query << "' is '"
        << strs[idx] << "', distance " << dist << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Closest to 'word' is 'world', distance 1
```

---

**Part 3**

I did comparison of timings using [200 most common English words](https://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-english-words/).

Compared Slow and Fast (with memoization) Levenstein implementations from Part 1 and 2.

It appeared that slow version is 8x slower than fast version for 5-letter strings and 5000x slower for 10-letter strings, which is Very-Very slow. This slowness happens only because of pure recursive nature with many repetitions.

All timings are below code in micro-seconds.

Also here I provide full code that did measurements.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/MvofbW5Pf)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

size_t Levenstein(std::string_view const & a, std::string_view const & b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
    if (b.size() == 0)
        return a.size();
    if (a.size() == 0)
        return b.size();
    if (a[0] == b[0])
        return Levenstein(a.substr(1), b.substr(1));
    return 1 + std::min(
        std::min(
            Levenstein(a          , b.substr(1)),
            Levenstein(a.substr(1), b          )
        ),  Levenstein(a.substr(1), b.substr(1))
    );
}

size_t LevensteinFast(std::string_view const & a, std::string_view const & b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
    thread_local std::vector<size_t> d_;
    d_.clear();
    d_.resize((a.size() + 1) * (b.size() + 1), size_t(-1));
    auto d = [&](size_t ia, size_t ib) -> size_t & {
        return d_[ia * (b.size() + 1) + ib];
    };
    std::function<size_t(size_t, size_t)> LevensteinInt =
        [&](size_t ia, size_t ib) -> size_t {
            if (d(ia, ib) != size_t(-1))
                return d(ia, ib);
            size_t dist = 0;
            if (ib >= b.size())
                dist = a.size() - ia;
            else if (ia >= a.size())
                dist = b.size() - ib;
            else if (a[ia] == b[ib])
                dist = LevensteinInt(ia + 1, ib + 1);
            else
                dist = 1 + std::min(
                    std::min(
                        LevensteinInt(ia,     ib + 1),
                        LevensteinInt(ia + 1, ib    )
                    ),  LevensteinInt(ia + 1, ib + 1)
                );
            d(ia, ib) = dist;
            return dist;
        };
    return LevensteinInt(0, 0);
}

std::tuple<size_t, size_t> FindClosest(std::vector<std::string> const & strs,
        std::string const & query, bool fast = true) {
    size_t minv = size_t(-1), mini = size_t(-1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
        size_t const dist = (fast ? LevensteinFast : Levenstein)(strs[i], query);
        if (dist < minv) {
            minv = dist;
            mini = i;
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(mini, minv);
}

double Time() {
    static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
}

int main() {
    // https://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-english-words/
    // 600 most common English words
    std::vector<std::string> const strs = {
        "as", "I", "his", "that", "he", "was", "for", "on", "are", "with", "they", "be", "at", "one", "have",
        "this", "from", "by", "hot", "word", "but", "what", "some", "is", "it", "you", "or", "had", "the", "of",
        "to", "and", "a", "in", "we", "can", "out", "other", "were", "which", "do", "their", "time", "if", "will",
        "how", "said", "an", "each", "tell", "does", "set", "three", "want", "air", "well", "also", "play", "small", "end",
        "put", "home", "read", "hand", "port", "large", "spell", "add", "even", "land", "here", "must", "big", "high", "such",
        "follow", "act", "why", "ask", "men", "change", "went", "light", "kind", "off", "need", "house", "picture", "try", "us",
        "again", "animal", "point", "mother", "world", "near", "build", "self", "earth", "father", "any", "new", "work", "part", "take",
        "get", "place", "made", "live", "where", "after", "back", "little", "only", "round", "man", "year", "came", "show", "every",
        "good", "me", "give", "our", "under", "name", "very", "through", "just", "form", "sentence", "great", "think", "say", "help",
        "low", "line", "differ", "turn", "cause", "much", "mean", "before", "move", "right", "boy", "old", "too", "same", "she",
        "all", "there", "when", "up", "use", "your", "way", "about", "many", "then", "them", "write", "would", "like", "so",
        "these", "her", "long", "make", "thing", "see", "him", "two", "has", "look", "more", "day", "could", "go", "come",
        "did", "number", "sound", "no", "most", "people", "my", "over", "know", "water", "than", "call", "first", "who", "may",
        "down", "side", "been", "now", "find", "head", "stand", "own", "page", "should", "country", "found", "answer", "school", "grow",
        "study", "still", "learn", "plant", "cover", "food", "sun", "four", "between", "state", "keep", "eye", "never", "last", "let",
        "thought", "city", "tree", "cross", "farm", "hard", "start", "might", "story", "saw", "far", "sea", "draw", "left", "late",
        "run", "don’t", "while", "press", "close", "night", "real", "life", "few", "north", "book", "carry", "took", "science", "eat",
        "room", "friend", "began", "idea", "fish", "mountain", "stop", "once", "base", "hear", "horse", "cut", "sure", "watch", "color",
        "face", "wood", "main", "open", "seem", "together", "next", "white", "children", "begin", "got", "walk", "example", "ease", "paper",
        "group", "always", "music", "those", "both", "mark", "often", "letter", "until", "mile", "river", "car", "feet", "care", "second",
        "enough", "plain", "girl", "usual", "young", "ready", "above", "ever", "red", "list", "though", "feel", "talk", "bird", "soon",
        "body", "dog", "family", "direct", "pose", "leave", "song", "measure", "door", "product", "black", "short", "numeral", "class", "wind",
        "question", "happen", "complete", "ship", "area", "half", "rock", "order", "fire", "south", "problem", "piece", "told", "knew", "pass",
        "since", "top", "whole", "king", "street", "inch", "multiply", "nothing", "course", "stay", "wheel", "full", "force", "blue", "object",
        "decide", "surface", "deep", "moon", "island", "foot", "system", "busy", "test", "record", "boat", "common", "gold", "possible", "plane",
        "stead", "dry", "wonder", "laugh", "thousand", "ago", "ran", "check", "game", "shape", "equate", "hot", "miss", "brought", "heat",
        "snow", "tire", "bring", "yes", "distant", "fill", "east", "paint", "language", "among", "unit", "power", "town", "fine", "certain",
        "fly", "fall", "lead", "cry", "dark", "machine", "note", "wait", "plan", "figure", "star", "box", "noun", "field", "rest",
        "correct", "able", "pound", "done", "beauty", "drive", "stood", "contain", "front", "teach", "week", "final", "gave", "green", "oh",
        "quick", "develop", "ocean", "warm", "free", "minute", "strong", "special", "mind", "behind", "clear", "tail", "produce", "fact", "space",
        "heard", "best", "hour", "better", "true", "during", "hundred", "five", "remember", "step", "early", "hold", "west", "ground", "interest",
        "reach", "fast", "verb", "sing", "listen", "six", "table", "travel", "less", "morning", "ten", "simple", "several", "vowel", "toward",
        "war", "lay", "against", "pattern", "slow", "center", "love", "person", "money", "serve", "appear", "road", "map", "rain", "rule",
        "govern", "pull", "cold", "notice", "voice", "energy", "hunt", "probable", "bed", "brother", "egg", "ride", "cell", "believe", "perhaps",
        "pick", "sudden", "count", "square", "reason", "length", "represent", "art", "subject", "region", "size", "vary", "settle", "speak", "weight",
        "general", "ice", "matter", "circle", "pair", "include", "divide", "syllable", "felt", "grand", "ball", "yet", "wave", "drop", "heart",
        "am", "present", "heavy", "dance", "engine", "position", "arm", "wide", "sail", "material", "fraction", "forest", "sit", "race", "window",
        "store", "summer", "train", "sleep", "prove", "lone", "leg", "exercise", "wall", "catch", "mount", "wish", "sky", "board", "joy",
        "winter", "sat", "written", "wild", "instrument", "kept", "glass", "grass", "cow", "job", "edge", "sign", "visit", "past", "soft",
        "fun", "bright", "gas", "weather", "month", "million", "bear", "finish", "happy", "hope", "flower", "clothe", "strange", "gone", "trade",
    };
    for (size_t K: {1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20}) {
        size_t const query_str_cnt = 10, total_str_cnt = 20;
        double avg_len = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> strK;
        for (size_t i = 0; (i + 1) * K <= strs.size(); ++i) {
            std::string s;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < K; ++j)
                s += strs[i * K + j] + " ";
            strK.push_back(s);
            avg_len += s.size();
        }
        avg_len /= strK.size();
        std::vector<std::string> strs_search(strK.begin(),
            strK.begin() + std::min<size_t>(total_str_cnt, strK.size()));
        
        for (size_t ifast = K <= 2 ? 0 : 1; ifast < 2; ++ifast) {
            double tim = 1000;
            for (size_t itest = 0; itest < (1 << 0); ++itest) {
                auto tb = Time();
                for (size_t i = 0; i < query_str_cnt; ++i) {
                    auto volatile t = FindClosest(strs_search, strK.at(strK.size() - 1 - i), ifast);
                }
                tb = Time() - tb;
                tim = std::min<double>(tim, tb / query_str_cnt / strs_search.size());
            }
            std::cout << std::fixed << "Avg time " << std::setprecision(2) << std::setw(9) << tim * 1'000'000
                << " mc-sec per " << (ifast ? "Fast" : "Slow") << " Levenstein distance of " << std::setprecision(1)
                << std::setw(5) << avg_len << " symbol strings" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Console output of timings:

```
Avg time     10.41 mc-sec per Slow Levenstein distance of   4.8 symbol strings
Avg time      1.58 mc-sec per Fast Levenstein distance of   4.8 symbol strings

Avg time  30444.71 mc-sec per Slow Levenstein distance of   9.6 symbol strings
Avg time      5.54 mc-sec per Fast Levenstein distance of   9.6 symbol strings

Avg time     12.56 mc-sec per Fast Levenstein distance of  14.4 symbol strings

Avg time     38.44 mc-sec per Fast Levenstein distance of  24.1 symbol strings

Avg time    154.76 mc-sec per Fast Levenstein distance of  48.1 symbol strings

Avg time    659.87 mc-sec per Fast Levenstein distance of 110.6 symbol strings
```

Comment: might be better to use string views instead of strings.

Comment: @Thomas , Good point! Updated my code to use [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was confused on how to implement this in code and this guidance helps a bunch! Thanks for the amazing answer!

Comment: Why this nice (and perfectly working!) answer didn't get a single Thumbsup, I'll never know...